# JQuery XML Parsing on error

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse XML in an Ajax response.
When the server returns a 200 everything works fine.
But it seems like XML parsing in JQuery is disabled on error.

```
statusCode:{
200:function(xml){alert($(xml).find("error").text());},
404:function(xml){alert($(xml).find("error").text());}
}
```

If I send a 200 I get the correct alert.
But if I change the response code to whatever error I like, I just get an empty alert box.
Am I plain stupid for sending text/xml on error, is this a bug in jquery or where am I going wrong?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),

> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same
> parameters as the success callback which is "success(data, textStatus,
> jqXHR)";
>
> if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as
> the error callback which is "error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)"

That means in your 404 callback "function(xml){alert($(xml).find("error").text());" the 'xml' is actually the jqXHR object and understandably $(xml).find("error").text() is nothing.

Comment: Thanks to your hint I got it solved:

I had to use

    $(xml.responseXML).find("error")

That way the response got transformed into a jQuery Object on which I could then perform the find()

Thanks